# Checking all checkboxes in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table setup like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check-all" />
        </th>
        <th>
            Title
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>Name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>Name 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm trying to have it so when the checkbox in the header with class 'check-all' is checked, it checks all the checkboxes below.

This is what I have, but it doesn't seem to work

```
        $('.check-all').click(
        function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));   
        }
    )
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should use [jQuery.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the closest table tag.

```
 $('.check-all').click(function() {
   $(this).closest('table').find("input:checkbox").attr('checked', this.checked);   
 });
```

Second.  If you are using jQuery 1.6 or higher you should use [jQuery.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
 $('.check-all').click(function() {
   $(this).closest('table').find("input:checkbox").prop('checked', this.checked);   
 });
```

Finally, for a boolean value from the check-all box you do not need the jQuery object you can simply use HTML DOM `this.checked`

Answer (score 0):

I lost track of parents. :) Try this:

```
$(this).closest("table").find("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
```

Edit:

P.S. @John Hartsock changed your syntax slightly. I left your syntax as is, but his syntax is better (or you you can just use .find(":checkbox"). I'm guessing that jquery is able to find checkboxes in a much more efficient way than getting all inputs and then checking the attribute "type" to see if it's a checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

[I wrote an article about this](http://www.iknowkungfoo.com/blog/index.cfm/2008/7/9/Check-All-Checkboxes-with-JQuery) a while back. It will be easier if you give all related check boxes the same class.

**UPDATE**

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iknowkungfoo/nax4f/1/) with the code copied here now that I've got more time.

HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <input type="checkbox" class="check-all" />
            </th>
            <th>Check All Below</th>
        </tr>
        <tr><th><hr /></th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="groupOne" /></td>
            <td>Name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="groupOne" /></td>
            <td>Name 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
var $_checkAll = $('.check-all');
var $_groupOne = $('.groupOne');

$_checkAll.click(function(){
    $_groupOne.prop('checked', $_checkAll.prop('checked'));
});

/* If I uncheck a groupOne checkbox, uncheck the related "check all" */
$_groupOne.click(function(){
    if ( !$(this).prop('checked') ) {
        $_checkAll.prop('checked', false );
    }
});

/* Checking the "check all" checkbox when all groupOne checkboxes 
have been checked is left as homework. */
```